# Number of times any Vedic mantra or a chalisa that should be repeated to worship maa Laxmi, Saraswati, Ganesh ,hanuman etc?

Tags: prayer, japa, chalisa

Is there any specific number of times , mentioned by any scriptures , which a common householder might chant for a successful worship of the deity ?

Specifically how many times should one chant any chalisa and the Vedic mantras of the deity , which will be fruitful to the devotee?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hanuman chalisa :100 times

जो ***सत*** बार पाठ कर कोई।

छूटहि बंदी महा सुख होइ।।

The person who ***recites this Hanuman Chalisa a hundred times*** every day with a pure heart will be freed from all worldly bondages and will attain bliss.

Comment: But @hope what about other chalisas? Like Saraswati Ganesh Laxmi Kali etc ? What should I do for them?

Comment: @SoumyadipDas most times it's mentioned in chalisas. Read it carefully, you will find.

Comment: Thank you very much @hope.

Answer (score 0):

Generally any mantras should be recited 108 times (100+8; extra 8 counts are done as prayaschitta for any mistakes done during chanting), 1008 times etc.. But 10 is also a valid number.

In Mahanirvana Tantra's 7th chapter Lord Shiva says this:

> **O Gentle One! In all daily prayers recitation shouldbe done one thousand and eight or a hundred and eight or ten times (79).** O Devi!
> the Shudras and Samanyas may observe any of the rites proclaimed by
> the Agamas, and by these they attain that which they desire (80). The
> three times of performance (of Sandhya) are at sunrise, at noon, and
> at sunset (81)

But when chanting is done for Purascharana then count should be N lac where N denotes the number of letters the mantra is made of. And in case of stotra recital usually the number of minimum chants is 3.

Comment: just wanted to clarify , are the chanting numbers same for mantra and chalisa?

Comment: No ..that is why I mentioned the rules for Stotras separately .. Hanuman Chalisa is a Stuti or Stotra. @SoumyadipDas